# Sql Limit clause based in input Parameter

Tags: sql, casting, limit, clause, exasol

I have been trying to find a solution for a limit-clause based on an input parameter from a Json-File. The current code looks somewhat like this

```
With myJsonTable (JsonText)
as (
Select JsonText)

Select * from Data
Where...

Limit 
  Case
   WHEN (Select JSON_VALUE(JsonText, '$."Amount"') From myJsonTable is not null
     THEN (Select JSON_VALUE(JsonText, '$."Amount"') From myJsonTable)
     ELSE (10000000)
  END
```

Which I cant seem to get work. The Output I am getting is

```
Non-negative integeter value expected in LIMIT clause
```

Is there a way to cast the select done? Trying different Selects anywhere in the Case clause caused the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exasol only allows constant expression in the limit clause, so it's not directly possible to specify a select statement that references `myJsonTable` there.

However, you can workaround this issue by using a approach similar to [SQL query for top 5 results without the use of LIMIT/ROWNUM/TOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468484/sql-query-for-top-5-results-without-the-use-of-limit-rownum-top)